# Reading Environment variable in ebpf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, ebpf

I am trying to create an `ebpf` program in `C` and want to read user set environment variables. Something similar to `getenv` in `C`.

I am unable to find a `bpf_helper()` function that does this job.

Does there exist a function for this purpose and if not, how can I implement it.

Comment: Does [this](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-security-module/patch/20190910115527.5235-14-kpsingh@chromium.org/) help?